# How to add - array into object mongodb + angular + node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

Hi I have document in mongodb and I try add new collection (array) using angular / node

my code looks loke:

```
$scope.items = {desc: "desc from form", price: "price from form";
Test.get({id.doc._id}, function(response) {
response.docArray.push($scope.items);
Test.update(response, function(res) {
$scope.items = {}
});
});
```

It's works only fist time - adds correct data - but if I try to add new data to new array - it's works but in all array i have the same data (first);

What should I change ?

use ( mongodb/ angular / ngResources )

Answer (score 0):

on server side its working - i think problem is with this code - 
if I submit array first time to existing document they save correct all data

but when i change $scope.item to new and submit - its save as new array but the data is the same as in first one array -

? 
its doesn't matter what I paste in to $scope.items - always new array have same info as first added array